# Why are Snell's law and Cauchy 's and Sellmeier's equations not valid for all of EM-waves?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum, refraction

Is this true that a x-ray or a soft gamma-ray would bend the most among all EM-waves while passing through two different optical materials? How can happen that so energetic rays must bend their trajectories as they were something so easy to bend? If the material doesn't absorb them what cause them to change trajectory,should there be some momentum exchange?